# Word for a follower of a Pied Piper

Tags: word-usage, pied-piping

The phrase [Pied Piper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied_Piper_of_Hamelin) is often used to suggest one who leads others down a questionable path.

I cannot, however, think of the best term to use to describe a "child" following said Pied Piper, in a analogous usage of the story.

What are some ideas for this? Ideally one could use it in a way that someone would rapidly understand the analogy, without requiring a detailed explanation from yourself.

Comment: Sheep! Rather than a mouse.

Comment: I love it! Good one.

Comment: Lemming comes to mind :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to *sheep* and *lemming*, which others have suggested:

- Single-word adjective: *Enchanted* or *charmed*.
- Single-word noun: *follower*.
- Adjectival expression: to have *drunk the kool-aid* or to be *under the spell*.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to emphasize the thrall under which the piper holds his subject, consider *[minion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/minion)*

> A follower or underling of a powerful person, especially a servile or unimportant one. [*Oxford Dictionary Online*]

If the innocence of the adherent is the focus, perhaps the noun, *naif* (or *[naive](https://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/naive)*)

> One who is artless, credulous, or uncritical. [*American Heritage Dictionary*]

Answer (score 0):

Q.The best term to use to describe a "child" following said Pied Piper.

A. Sacrificial lamb

Reasons- Lambs are young and innocent as are children. Lambs are animals that flock together so can be led.

A. Drunken sailor

Reasons - A sailor is a low ranking member of an armed force who has been trained to follow orders. An intoxicated person can easily be duped.

A. Zombie

Reasons - Zombies follow in large groups with minimal instincts. They respond to noises to search out the living to satisfy their hunger.

Comment: This answer would be stronger if supported by references that support your reasoning (e.g a dictionary definition of "sacrificial lamb").